# Attach Excel file in word document using vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Can anyone one help me with the code to attach excel file as a object to word document using vba macro ?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Word macro record to record a macro, and then change the macro code to what you want.
the macro is like this below:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Excel.Sheet.12", FileName _
    :="C:\Book1.xlsx", LinkToFile _
    :=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
    "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{90140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe" _
    , IconIndex:=1, IconLabel:="Book1.xlsx"
End Sub
```